# Why does c++ vector cause oom-killer?

Tags: c++, vector, out-of-memory, embedded-linux

The code needs to find and process files that have not yet been processed on embedded-linux. 
getDir is used to return the sorted contents of a directory. 
The code below works perfectly after processing several few dozen or maybe more than 100 files but then dies with oom-killer.
Is this a bad way to use c++ vectors (loop vector inside loop vector)?
Might this method be causing the oom-killer? 
Is there another approach that might work without blowing up?
Shouldn't each vector be destroyed as it goes out of scope?
Does new/delete need to be used instead?
Also: valgrind for finding memory leaks is not integrated in the sdk for this processor (TI DM368) but the code is very short and there are no new statements. Note: the actual code checks an sql database for files that have already been processed but this code still caused oom-killer with the sql code commented out so it has been left out for simplicity. The file path format is /YYYYmmdd/HH/MMSS.SS.ext.

```
void getDir (string dir, vector<string> &files) {
    ...
    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        files.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));
    closedir(dp);
    sort(files.begin(), files.end());

while (true) {
    vector<string> days;
    getDir(database_location, days);
    for (uint d=0; d<days.size(); d++) {
        vector<string> hours;
        getDir(database_location+days[d], hours);
        for (uint h=0; h<hours.size(); h++) {
            vector<string> files;
            string dir = database_location+days[d]+"/"+hours[h];
            getDir(dir, files);
            for (uint f=0; f<files.size(); f++) process(dir, files[f]);
```

Comment: How deep does this get with the final `for-loop` (with `process()`) commented out? Even with a few hundred files sitting at 200-chars in a hundred file path names including the paths you're only looking at about 250-300K memory. You could shorten this up to *only* include the final full-names by building the file list *first*, then std::for_each() on it. I.e. use a 3-layered `readdir()` loop to build your filenames, and once they're *all* built (without the intermediate vectors) sort *that*, then run them all through `process()`. the results should be similar order, but less memory impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Linux OOM killer is notoriously dumb. By default, don't start blaming your own code.
2. You only have three vectors, of reasonable sizes. (If the vector size is unreasonable, it would be because the number of files in a single dir is also unreasonable).
3. You don't need `new/delete`.

Since you're not going to be running multi-threaded, consider making the three vectors `static`. Hack, but might just work.

Answer (score 0):

To save some memory, you can try using [string::shrink_to_fit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/shrink_to_fit/) and [vector::shrink_to_fit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/) once each string or vector is at it's final size (but not before that, of course).

Another thing might be, do not gather `hours` to vector first, if that is a very long vector, instead process each directory entry as you read it, and sort everything later somehow.